# Why does Android Studio keep using a lot of memory even after closing all opened projects?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks, android-gradle-plugin

I only noticed this yesterday after I closed my projects and decided to take a look at the Task Manager, and this is what I found:
[image]
2.7 GB worth of memory usage.
I didn't close the Android Studio itself, rather I closed all my opened projects (sometimes I opened two or three at the same time, but in the above case, that was after only having one project opened and ran it for a minute on AVD), so I was back in the "Welcome to Android Studio" dialog.

Now, if I remember correctly, this wasn't always the case. I recently updated my Android Studio, and some things have been acting weird. Like, one of my AVDs (API 29) would use about 37% of my CPU even if it's doing nothing, literally nothing.
I'm pretty sure that before the update, when I closed all my opened projects, Android Studio would release the resource (in this case RAM) and get back to using only 500MB or something, which is fine. 2.7 GB **AFTER ALL** the project's closed is not fine.

Anyone having the same issue?
Is this a bug?
Is this Gradle Daemon doing its thing? If it is, is there a setting to stop it on project's closing?
This is my current Memory Settings:
[image]